# Can Emacs show me where a specific function is called?

Tags: c, emacs

Is there a way in Emacs to find out which other places in the code call a specific function?  With my current setup (GNU emacs 23.1.1, C codebase), I normally have to search the whole codebase for the function name to see which other functions call it. It would be nice if I could efficiently display all the names of the functions that call this specific function that I'm looking at.

Comment: I am using Emacs for C programming compiling with GCC 4.4.3 on Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `xcscope` for this. It's a library that makes Emacs interact with the external `cscope` tool.

After setup, you can use `cscope-find-functions-calling-this-function` to get a list of source code destinations that call a certain function.

http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs186/fa05/debugging/xcscope.el
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CScopeAndEmacs

Answer (score 11):

You can use `semantic-symref` function (`C-c , G`) from CEDET package.  It can use GNU Global or CTags databases to find callers if they exist. It could also parse sources to find occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

here is a snippet from my old .emacs file

it does: ask for thing to find from etags-tagfile (find-tag-tag)
grep for it according to mode

```
(defun find-caller (tagname)
  "Find occurences of tagname in files in the current directory
matching extension of current file."
  (interactive (list (find-tag-tag "Find caller: ")))
  (let ((cmd "grep -n "))
    (cond
     ((member major-mode '(lisp-mode cmulisp-mode))
      (grep (concat cmd "-i '" tagname "' *.lisp")))
     ((eq major-mode 'c-mode)
      (grep (concat cmd "'" tagname "' *.[ch]")))
     ((member major-mode '(latex-mode tex-mode))
      (grep (concat cmd "-i '" tagname "' *.tex")))
     ((eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode)
      (grep (concat cmd "'" tagname "' *.el")))
     (t (grep (concat cmd "'" tagname "' *"))))))
```

Comment: just FYI: CEDET can use grep to find callers